# Using ES2017 async with jQuery .ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm learning about the [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) feature introduced in ES2017, and I couldn't seem to get the following to work:

```
async function sayHelloAsync() {
  let {autosave} = await browser.storage.local.get('autosave');
  if (autosave) {
    $('#helloButton').click();
  }
}

$(sayHelloAsync);
```

I have managed a workaround for my needs in my small application, but I'm wondering *why* this would not work. As soon as I remove the `async`, it works as expected. I also have other custom event bindings which use `async` functions as callbacks, and they work just fine.

I am using Google Chrome 57 on Linux.

**Update**

I updated my code sample to remove the confusion about my need for loaded DOM and jQuery.

Comment: Why would you use async and `.ready`? It's likely that the document's `ready` event would have already fired before the async script is run.

Comment: What is the purpose of running you function with jQuery `$(sayHelloAsync);`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I'm confused. Wouldn't the `ready` event _cause_ the `async` function to run? Thanks

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov - to ensure the DOM is loaded before running my function

Comment: Why do you need DOM in this case?

Comment: @Andy if that's the case, then you don't need jQuery.

Comment: Async function is simply a function that returns `Promise`. No jQuery involved in this simple case.

Comment: Your `async` function no corresponding `await` statement on the inside

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPD:** As Quentin mentioned, the issues was already fixed and jQuery 3.6.0 (and maybe few earlier versions) works as expected.

I have checked `jQuery` source code and here is a check it performs to find out what the argument is:

```
isFunction: function( obj ) {
  return jQuery.type( obj ) === "function";
}
```

And `jQuery.type( obj )` returns `object` not `function` as expected. That's probably a bug in `jQuery`, but that's why the function is not executed.

Dug a bit more and `jQuery` calls `toString.call( obj )` ti determine a type and tries map the result to known type. It cannot and that's why it returns `object`.

So the problem here is with `jQuery` not with your async function.

Comment: A workaround would be to wrap the `sayHelloAsync` with a anonomys, not async function.

For example like `$(() => sayHelloAsync());` or `$(function () { sayHelloAsync() });`

Comment: Note that somewhere between jQuery 3.1.0 and 3.6.0 this bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native js

```
document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded',  async function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OP found an answer to their problem that isn't actually an answer to the question title. I wanted to await the document.ready function in a Puppeteer script I was writing that utilised jQuery.

So here's how I did it; which answers the question as titled:

You can wrap the document.ready function in a promise that resolves when the page is ready.

```
  //Wrap document ready function in a promise to be able to await it
  async domReady() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $(document).ready(() => {
        resolve("ready");
      });

      //Any reason for rejection could go here and have a call to reject(error);
    });

    return promise;
  }
```

Then if you want to wait for the document to load:

```
await domReady();
// The rest of your dependant code goes here...
```